# Open CV import CV2 error in Pycharm "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found."

Tags: python, opencv

I am attempting to use OpenCV and have the most up-to-date installation of OpenCv downloaded and am unable to install/import it either in Pycharm or using my command prompt in my Windows system. I receive the following error from both: "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found." I looked at some folks that had similar issues and made sure I added the "C:\opencv\build\bin" to my path in environment variable. However I still receive the same error. Happy to answer any questions to help. Thank you.

EDIT:

I got frustrated so removed python and then re-installed; now face the following error: "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cv2 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for cv2"

I tried the below solutions prior to taking these steps. As always appreciate any and all help. Thank you so much

Comment: did you restart pycharm after editing your path?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28284307/import-cv2-failed-installing-opencv-for-python-2-7-for-windows

Comment: are you sure you have in site-packages cv2.pyd? I actually had a similar problem, I had it installed, I did the uninstall with pip and then install again and it worked again..

Comment: Hi, tried your solutions to no avail; uninstalled then reinstalled python and now facing different error but still no solution.